# Unserializing the string value passed through mysqli_real_escape_string() and serialize() functions

Tags: php, mysql

I passed the `$post` variable through the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `serialize()` functions in PHP as follows:

```
$post = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, serialize($item));
```

Then I inserted the `$post` value in a MySQL database. The stored data looks like below formats in the database:

```
a:1:{s:9:"title";s:37:"This is just a test -Title";}
```

or

```
a:1:{s:3:"post";s:7369:"This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---This is just a test ---- TEXT---";}
```

How can I generate only text values of `$post` variable before inserting them into the database (i.e. `This is just a test -Title` instead of `a:1:{s:9:"title";s:37:"This is just a test -Title";}`).

Comment: What is the format of `$item`?

Comment: @BadWolf, `$item` format is as `Array ( [title] => This is just a test -Title )` which is generated using `simple HTML dom` library.

Comment: What about `echo $item['title'];` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of serializing the array you can simply grab the element out of the array and insert it into the database directly instead. Don't forget to sanitize your variables!

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $item['title']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `serialize()` the variables before inserting the information into the database; you can just escape the value:

```
$post = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $item["title"]);
```

Then you use `$post` in your query to insert the value. This will result in just having the value in database.